# add tooltips to dates in angular-material calendar

Tags: angular, angular-material

Trying to add tooltip to angular material calendar dates.I tried with matToolTip but nothing comes up on hover.

```
<mat-calendar [dateClass]="dateClass()" [startAt]="month" [selected]="selectedDate"
      (selectedChange)="onSelect($event)"  matTooltip="Info about the action">
    </mat-calendar>
```

Comment: Do you have the MatTooltipModule imported somewhere?

Comment: are you asking about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59458789/angular-material-date-picker-how-to-show-the-title/59461291#59461291 ?

Comment: Doesnt this show the same tooltip message regardless where the mouse cursor is hovering on any day cell? Is it possible to show different tooltip messages on different days?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please see this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krbhxb) example. I've played around with the imports and configuration and the only surprising thing I found was that a material theme was required before the tooltip would appear. See the following in the `styles.scss`:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

Other than that, I've found that the following imports are required:

- BrowserAnimationsModule
- MatDatepickerModule
- MatNativeDateModule (or some other date provider)
- MatTooltipModule

Comment: Its not displaying anything to me

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I see the tooltip fine in Chrome & FireFox. I'm suspecting there's something else going on with your browser or maybe some company proxy in that case. I'd suggest checking the console for any errors or the network tab to check if something is being blocked.